# Why are these switches connected to ground?

Tags: inductor, wiring

Sorry for the vague title. This is a schematic of a Nerf Rayven foam dart gun:

[image]

Why did they make the connections that I circled in red? I'm guessing it has something to do with the inductors on the left side of the motors, but what exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly for safety reasons. The idea behind this is to stop the mechanics of the gun as quickly as possible by shorting the motors when the door on top is opened or the ammo clip is removed. Putting your finger into one of these locations could cause injuries when the flywheels used to accelerate the foam bullets are still rotating due to inertia.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? / safety / braking.

With motors grounded there will be substantial drag if the motor shafts are turned, due to their acting like shorted alternators. This is unlikely to be an intended effect but exists.

If the motor is grounded when not used there is minimum chance of a fault elsewhere allowing the motor to operate.

If a contact is floating it has the potential to be shorted to something which can cause a problem. If grounded then such a short would cause the PTC to overheat and no action to occur.

In practice, it probably makes extremely little difference in most cases. In the cases where it does make a difference, the difference is a positive one from a safety point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a Nerf Rayven foam dart gun is, but connecting the bottom of the switches to ground instead of leaving them open actively shorts the motor in some of the cases instead of leaving it disconnected.  That would provide a little viscous breaking.  Whether that is intentional and/or useful I don't know without a description of what the device is supposed to do and how it works.